# How can I handle ball interaction with lanes in a pinball game?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics

In a pinball game, how can I handle collision or constraints on the ball for convincing movement on those highway rails/tracks?

I assume using physics and a mesh collider would not work, even when the poly count is really high the ball still bashes into all those faces instead of hugging a smooth, round wall. I could constrain the ball to a spline but I foresee problems with the balls speed and proper physics.

I'm wondering if it is possible to tell the ball that mesh corners below a certain degree should be treated as round. Perhaps only when coming from a certain angle?

Comment: Note that in pinball terminology, "those highway rails/tracks" are called "lanes". (and sometimes "inlanes", "outlanes", "loops", "ramps", or "habitrails", depending on specific characteristics of the lane)

Comment: Thanks, this gives me some more opportunities to find some answers.

Comment: What about putting Physics computation on hold when the ball enters in a ramp, make it following a spline, and wake up physics computation when it's on the other side?